# Culture conversion of datetime in javascript/jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime, cultureinfo

I want to convert the datetime format according to the culture through javaScript/jQuery.

Ex: Let we have a date:

```
var starDate = "7/4/2013 9:00:00 AM"
```

then after conversion this into french it should be `"4 juillet 2013 09:00"`

like we have in **c#**:

```
DateTime dteStartTime = "7/4/2013 9:00:00 AM";
dteStartTime.ToString("f", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA"));
```

it will convert this datetime into `"4 juillet 2013 09:00"`

Comment: you can treat is as a view using toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, toLocaleString...

Answer (score 4):

Working with dates in JavaScript without a helper library is very painful and error prone. Have you tried using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? It has support for many languages including French (Canada).

Comment: is this work with your browser locale? I need something where I put the locale like in my example above in c#.

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh You need to pass along your language string and use it in Moment.js to convert a date to the language you want. Look at the `.lang()` method in Moment.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the globalize.js. Just make sure you pass a correct culture code. Maybe it will better idea just to pass the converted date from C# as string?

Comment: Agreed -- if it isn't going to change, it makes more sense to have the view on the server side take care of it. I was assuming it would change via JavaScript on the client side.